# How to isolate a local application completely (intercept inward and outward traffic) using mitmproxy?

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm using mitmproxy on my macOS machine. The requirement is simple - I would like to isolate a local application (java or node) completely. All the inward and outward traffic to/from this application should go through mitmproxy.

I tried looking for answers but couldn't find one with concrete example or explanation. Can someone help here?

Transparent mode of mitmproxy is definitely one approach but it gives me everything (all the traffic) in one go.

Comment: MacOS has the functionality of an "Per-App VPN". That should help you to isolate it. Just using a proxy isn't a good solution as the app simply can ignore the proxy settings and bypass the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Robert. I'm building something where I need to isolate the application. Actually I'm building a solution where this is a subproblem